# Error: GTK library is not installed or installed version is not compatible

Tags: installation, centos7, intel-xdk, gtk2

I'm trying to install the Intel XDK for Linux under CentOS 7.3 (7.3.1611)

But I'm facing a problem witch I'm not able to solve:

Message:

`GTK library is not installed or installed version is not compatible
The GTK library is not installed or installed version of the library is not     compatible. The graphical user interface of the product requires gtk version 2.20 or higher. Contact your system administrator to install a compliant version of gtk for the INTEL64 architecture or install the product on a compliant system.`

**In my OS, I've already gtk+ 2.4 installed, but the installer of Intel XDK can't see the package.**

[image]

I've these packages installed:

`yum install gtk*:`

```
Package gtk2-2.24.28-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gtk2-devel-2.24.28-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gtk2-devel-docs-2.24.28-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Package gtk3-3.14.13-20.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gtk3-devel-3.14.13-20.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Hey! Did you solve this problem. I am facing the exact same issue

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336005/intel-xdk-not-working-on-centos-7-64bits-vmware-virtual-machine/33337029#33337029